# How do you copy only a word within () in vim?

Tags: vim

I know how to select everything within () with "vi("
but how to select only one word like when I double-clic a word in VSCode and just copy it to clipboard ?

Comment: How do you mean? Could you give a minimal example? I guess my confusion is: is it any _arbitrary_ word, the _first_ word, the _last_ word, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cursor is at begin of the word: `ye` or `ve<esc>`

If the cursor is within the word: `yiw` or `viw<esc>`

Answer (score 1):

Do `:help i(` and scroll around. `:help motion.txt` will blow your mind.